# exit status 1 expected primary-expression before 'if'

Tags: arduino

I have been working on an Arduino project and ha ve come ascross this problem in verification : exit status 1
expected primary-expression before 'if'

I have searched for solutions all over the web but the only solutions are making sure to define things properly but as far as I am aware they are fine...

My code is :

```
//Code for Machine

int sensorPin1 = A0; //select pin input for LDR1//
int sensorValue1 = 0; //variable to store value from LDR1//
int sensorPin2 = A1; //pin for LDR2//
int sensorValue2 = 0; //variable to store value from LDR2//
int pistonNum = 0; //variable to determin which piston to activate//

#define piston1Out 1 // is defined as pin #1//
#define piston1In 2 // is defined as pin #2//
#define piston2Out 3 // is defined as pin #3//
#define piston2In 4 // is defined as pin #4//
#define relay1 5 //is defined as pin #5//
#define relay2 6 //is defined as pin #6//

void setup() { //Setup runs once//

pinMode(piston1Out, OUTPUT); //Set  as an output//
pinMode(piston1In, OUTPUT); //Set  as an output//
pinMode(piston2Out, OUTPUT); //Set  as an output//
pinMode(piston2In, OUTPUT); //Set  as an output//
pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT); //set as an output//
pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT); //set as an output//
}

void loop() {

  //read value from sensor:
  sensorValue1 = analogRead(sensorPin1);  
  sensorValue2 = analogRead(sensorPin2); 

if((sensorValue1 < 820) && if(sensorValue2 > 820)); { //If first sensor is below threshold and second is above then activate first piston//
    digitalWrite(piston1In,HIGH);
digitalWrite(piston1Out,LOW); //Pistons Out
digitalWrite(relay1,HIGH); //turns the relay for the first piston on//

delay(100);

digitalWrite(relay1,LOW); //turns the relay for the first piston off//
digitalWrite(piston1Out,HIGH);
digitalWrite(piston1In,LOW); //piston IN//
digitalWrite(relay1,HIGH); //relay on - activate piston//

delay(100);

digitalWrite(relay1, LOW); //piston off//
   }
  else if((sensorValue1 < 820) && if(sensorValue2 < 820)) { //If both sensors are below threshold then activate the second piston//
   digitalWrite(piston1In,HIGH);
digitalWrite(piston1Out,LOW); //Pistons Out
digitalWrite(relay1,HIGH); //turns the relay for the first piston on//

delay(100);

digitalWrite(relay1,LOW); //turns the relay for the first piston off//
digitalWrite(piston1Out,HIGH);
digitalWrite(piston1In,LOW); //piston IN//
digitalWrite(relay1,HIGH); //relay on - activate piston//

delay(100);

digitalWrite(relay1On, LOW); //piston off//
  }  
  else if((sensorValue1 > 820) && if(sensorValue2 > 820)) { //If both are above threshold then activate no pistons//
    pistonNum = 1
   }
else {
  pistonNum = 0
}


delay(50);
}
```

Help?

Comment: Your `if` statements are not correctly written: you should use `if ((sensorValue1 < 820) && (sensorValue2 > 820)) { ... }`. I removed your second `if` and no `;` before the braces.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding, I solved this a while ago now but many thanks! So sorry that I didn't say anything - in all honesty I had forgotten :/

Answer (score 0):

Your if is written incorrectly. You wrote

```
if((sensorValue1 < 820) && if(sensorValue2 > 
820));
```

There are two things wrong with this. First, correct the second if statement by just simply getting rid of it. Second, delete the semicolon. If you ran with the semicolon, it will compile, but it will cause all of the code in the if statement not to run.
Here is the corrected line:

```
if((sensorValue1 < 820) && (sensorValue2 > 
820)){/*Your code*/}
```

Glad I could help!